# ListView with multiple elements in one row

Tags: android, listview

I try to get multiple elements in one row with ListView (Like float:left in html/css) but it won't work.

How can I achieve - for example - that I have 2 or 3 elements in portrait mode and 6 or 8 in landscape. Depending on the width of the elements.

buttonlist.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintWidth="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonText"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_button"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="ButtonName"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Float-Test"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"></ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Which point am I missing, or is it just the wrong way?

Cheers,
Chriz

Answer (score 0):

Is `buttonlist.xml` the layout for your list items? If so, you can just add whatever other components you need to display there however you like.

And if you want a different look and feel for different screen orientations, you need to create screen-specific layouts in appropriate directories, such as `res/layout/sw-600dp`. See [support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) for more information.

If you're supporting different data displayed based on orientation, you'll need to make sure your adapter handles it properly as well.